# $\lim_{x \to \infty}e^{x-x^2}$

Tags: limits, limits-without-lhopital

I am teaching calculus and am wanting to put the following question on a test

$$
\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}e^{x-x^2}
$$

I know this limit is 0, but as I try to show it rigorously (I mean justifying the steps, but no $\epsilon,\delta$) I am running into problems.

I know that $e^{x-x^2}=\frac{e^x}{e^{x^2}}$ but this doesn't simplify. Intuitively, $e^{x^2}$ grows faster than $e^x$ so the quotient approaches 0, but this seems a bit hand-wavey.

Maybe since $e^x$ is continuous, we can apply the limit directly to $x-x^2$ and get nonsense like $\infty-\infty^2$. So if we factor we get $x(1-x)$ and note that $x\rightarrow\infty$ while $1-x\rightarrow-\infty$ so we get $\infty\cdot-\infty$ which again intuitively is $-\infty$ but it doesn't really make sense to multiply infinities. Nonetheless, if we "accept" this and abuse the notation we get $\frac{1}{e^{\infty}}$ which goes to 0 as well.

I feel like I am over complicating this and I don't want to ask a question that I can't explain clearly. How would you explain this without using an $\epsilon,\delta$ proof?

EDIT: Thanks for all of the responses. Obviously there are multiple ways to think about this, but with how I have been teaching using $e^{x-x^2}=e^{x^2(\frac{1}{x}-1)}$ which goes to $\frac{1}{e^{x^2}}$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$ seems like the "best" way to explain it. I do however like the squeeze theorem argument and might make it a bonus to prove this limit using squeeeze.

Comment: or $$e^{-x^2\left(1-\frac{1}{x}\right)}$$ and this tends to zero

Comment: One simple way is to factor $x - x^2 = -\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right)^2 + \frac{1}{4}$.

Comment: Or $x-x^2\to-\infty$, therefore $e^{x-x^2}\to 0$ for $x\to\infty$.

Comment: @NashJ Sorry for overlooking your edit.

Comment: If you know L'Hopital's rule the you can use it and limit properties on $e^{x}/e^{x^2}$ and get the answer.

Comment: sorry, I didn't notice the tag, never mind (though the lhopital solution is actually pretty cool)

Comment: Maybe it is not completely correct to affirm that  "$e^{x-x^2}=e^{x^2(\frac{1}{x}-1)}$ which goes to $\frac{1}{e^{x^2}}$ as $x\rightarrow\infty$" but it should be stated that ${x^2(\frac{1}{x}-1)}\to -\infty$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint:

1)use continuity of exponential function.

2) use $e^{x-x^2}=e^{x^2(\frac{1}{x}-1)}$

3) note that $\lim_{x \to \infty}(\frac{1}{x}-1)=-1$

Answer (score 7):

Note that since $e^x>x$

$$0\le e^{x-x^2}=\frac{1}{e^{x^2-x}}\le\frac{1}{x^2-x}\to0$$

thus for squeeze theorem

$$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}e^{x-x^2}=0$$

Answer (score 2):

**hint**
Since
$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}x (1-x)=-\infty ,$$

$$(\forall \epsilon>0) \;\; (\exists A>0 ) \;:$$
$$x>A \implies x (1-x)<\ln (\epsilon) $$
 $$\implies e^{x-x^2}<\epsilon $$
then

$$\lim_{x\to+\infty}e^{x-x^2}=0$$

Answer (score 1):

if you accept that $\lim_{x\to\infty}e^x = \infty$ then certainly also:
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{e^x}e = \infty
$$
now for $x\gt1$ we have 
$$
\bigg(\frac{e^x}e \bigg)^x \gt \frac{e^x}e
$$
so
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\bigg(\frac{e^x}e \bigg)^x = \infty
$$
i.e.
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} e^{x^2-x} = \infty
$$
and
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty} e^{x-x^2} = 0
$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** you have for large $x$ :$ \exp(- x^2)\leq\exp(x - x^2)\leq \frac{1}{x²}$ then use squeez theorem you get $\lim \exp(x - x^2)=0$ for $x \to +\infty$

Answer (score 0):

$x - x^2 \sim - x^2$ in $\infty$ so $x-x^2 \to -\infty$ in $\infty$ hence $\exp(x - x^2) \to 0$ in $\infty$

Answer (score 0):

Another attempt:

Let $x\gt 0:$

$0\lt e^{-x^2} e^x\lt e^{-x^2} e^{x^2/2} =$

$e^{-x^2/2}  = \dfrac{1}{e^{x^2/2} }$,  for $x \gt 2.$

Can you take it from here ?

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple solution using your simplification:

We rise x to the power:
$$e^{x-x^2}=\frac{e^x}{e^{x^2}}=(\frac{e}{e^{2}})^x$$
and we know that $$\frac{e}{e^{2}}<1$$
So we conclude that:
$$\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}e^{x-x^2} = \lim\limits_{x\rightarrow\infty}(\frac{e}{e^{2}})^x = 0$$

Comment: $e^{x^2} \neq (e^2)^x=e^{2x}$